# cartodb torque heat wizard disappeared

Tags: carto, heat-map, torque

I checked yesterday and today (2nd of December 2015).  The cartodb 'torque heat' disappeared from the wizard.

Is it something known or temporary?

Here is the information of what is (or should be) the 'torque heat' system:
http://blog.cartodb.com/introducing-heatmaps/

Answer (score 1):

The Torque Heat wizard is called "Heatmaps" now.

Notice that this and other Torque options will only appear for point datasets, as right now Torque doesn't work with polygons neither lines.

Comment: thanks you are right ... 'heatmaps' does also Torque. Activation of 'Torque' by just switch on the 'animated button'